# Node.js fs.watchFile, Is it possible for it to check for changes once and no more?

Tags: javascript, node.js

new to node.js and just looking through a doc on the watchFile "module"?
(I don't know if you call it module or method or whatever)

My current code looks like so:

```
var fs = require("fs");

console.log("Started");
var file = fs.readFileSync("./files/checked.txt");
console.log("Initial file content: "+file);

fs.watchFile("./files/checked.txt",function(current, previous) {
    console.log("File changed!");
    file = fs.readFileSync("./files/checked.txt");
    console.log("New file content: "+file);
});
```

It runs perfectly fine, yet was wondering how I could implement it so that once the file is changed once, it stops checking it.

I realized that the file is infinitely and always being checked, and decided to see what surrounding it with an always true loop would do, I received memory leak errors(because node won't let you have more that 11 file listeners(unless changed))... This made me wonder, is it possible to make the file listener be disabled after the file has been changed once.

NOTE: I'm sure there must be some sort of rough way like changing the filename when node detects a change, yet that doesn't sound like the best of ideas. Any interesting suggestions you have to offer would be great, I don't know why this feature would be useful yet(someone will find something).

### EDIT

DEPRECATED, use `fs.watch()` [Official Docs](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener)

Comment: About the edits. As a matter of style, Stack Overflow likes to keep questions and answers separate.

Comment: okay, I removed the answer, and left the deprecated note

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that [`fs.watchFile()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener) is deprecated.  Use `fs.watch()` instead.

Again, from documentation, `watch` returns a [`fs.FSwatcher`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_fswatcher) which has a `close()` method that stops watching.

Note that watch's callback is a bit different, `function(event, filename)`, where event can be either rename or change.

Comment: thank you, node is changing rapidly and I suppose I cannot rely on outdated tutorials :) And, thanks for the `close();`

Comment: I changed my code to use `fs.watch()` and my `console.log` is printing the sentence `File changed` and `New file content: *****` twice, instead of once.... http://s29.postimg.org/z4lyndznr/double.png

Comment: Not sure why that might be, but you might want to console.log the events received in the callback.

Comment: According to [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar) `fs.watch` "Sometimes reports events twice."  I don't know any of the details, but I happened to read that earlier today... maybe it's relevant...

Comment: I don't use watch that much.  Could be.

Comment: Yeah, I ran your code and got the same results. Myth confirmed

Comment: I don't see a `close()` anywhere in that pastebin, though.... all I did was add the event logging.

Comment: yes, yet all `close()` will do is stop updating the check, not stop double repeat returns. I already tested `close()` to work

Comment: Cannon fodder for another question "fs.watch() double fires", maybe someone knows something

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812637/node-js-fs-watch-outputs-multiple-times-for-single-change

Comment: `chokidar` also reports events multiple times.